# OS X terminal command to create a file named on current date

Tags: macos, bash, date, terminal

I have set up a cron task and I want to save the output to a file. The file should have the name based on the time at which the cron was executed (eg.: 20110317-113051.txt).

My actual cron command is as follows:

```
lynx -dump http://somesite/script.php > /Volumes/dev0/textfile.txt
```

I want the `textfile` to be replaced by some sort of unique time stamp.

I've tried

```
lynx -dump http://somesite/script.php > $(date).txt
```

but I receive an error that the command is ambiguous.

Thanks for your help!

Sorin

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `date` command can be given a format to determine exactly what form it generates dates in. It looks as if you want `$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S).txt`. With this format, the output of `date` should be free of spaces, parentheses, etc., which might otherwise confuse the shell or the `lynx` command.

See http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/date.1.html for documentation of the `date` command and http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/strftime.3.html for documentation of the format string, which is the same as for the `strftime` function in the standard library.

Answer (score 15):

You need to quote the file name, since date by default will have special characters in it:

```
lynx -dump http://somesite/script.php > "$(date).txt"
```

As @Gareth says though, you should specify a format string for date, so that you get a more readable/manageable file name, e.g.

```
lynx -dump http://somesite/script.php > "$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S).txt"
```

Comment: @DarshanMothreja: sure - why not - see the [man page for `date`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/date).